# $Windows.~WS folder in C:\ drive after Windows 10 Installation, Upgrade or Media Creation?

Tags: windows-10, windows-installation, windows-10-upgrade

I have a hidden folder on my C:\ drive called $Windows.~WS that's 3 GB large after my Windows 10 upgrade.

Disk clean and CCleaner even with system files removal didn't remove it, so I'm wondering if it's safe to manually SHIFT+DEL it?

Comment: Updated answer with details added.

Comment: A more complete and comprehensive answer - http://superuser.com/a/961470/183467 - Question title Improvement will prevent DUPLICATE questions as it covers all 3 scenarios for this folder generation

Answer (score 5):

When I downloaded the Windows 10 Media Creation Utility and ran it, I **chose the create media for another PC** option.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows-10/media-creation-tool-install

> **Run the tool:**
>
> Run the tool, if you didn't already select Run. (You need
>   to be an Administrator on the PC to run it.)
>
> If you're upgrading this PC, select Upgrade this PC now, and then
>   follow the instructions to finish the upgrade.
>
> –or–
>
> If you want to create media for a different PC, select **Create
>   installation media for another PC**. Use this table to choose the
>   edition of Windows 10 that you want to create media for.

Additional article with detailed screen shots:

http://www.7tutorials.com/how-download-windows-10-and-create-your-own-installation-media

During the installation media creation process, there were these options:

- x32
- x64
- Both

I chose to only create x64 .iso, even though I was thinking might to have a copy of both.

But from the folders files on C:\ drive, it apparently downloaded the WIM/ ESD files for both.

> C:\$Windows.~WS\Sources\installx64.esd
>   C:\$Windows.~WS\Sources\installx86.esd ..
>   C:\$Windows.~WS\Sources\Windows\x64\sources\install.wim
>   C:\$Windows.~WS\Sources\Windows\x64\sources\boot.wim ..
>   C:\$Windows.~WS\Sources\Windows\x86\sources\install.wim
>   C:\$Windows.~WS\Sources\Windows\x86\sources\boot.wim

The tool then can create a DVD or USB setup drive. 
I chose to create .iso file for Win 10 x64 and then saved it to an external HDD.

As per this Microsoft forums thread, it seems safe to eliminate.

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_install/is-it-safe-to-delete-the-hidden-folder-windowsws/cb24d5c3-e233-45fd-8358-573aed1331d0?auth=1

**Answer 1:**

> max green replied on  July 30, 2015See
>
> They are both temporary directories used by windows to update your
>   system. It is safe to delete both to reclaim valuable space.
>
> Microsoft has not updated the disk cleanup tool to delete $Windows.~WS
>   yet (but you can delete it manually).
>
> To delete them you need to change permissions first.
>
> Right-click start, Command Prompt (admin)
>
> Copy and paste each set of commands and press enter
>
> You might need to press Y - to delete and change permissions
>
> If it does not work and you get "Access Denied" errors - repeat the
>   instructions again
>
> ```
> takeown /F C:\$Windows.~BT\* /R /A
> icacls C:\$Windows.~BT\*.* /T /grant administrators:F
> rmdir /S /Q C:\$Windows.~BT\
> takeown /F C:\$Windows.~WS\* /R /A
> icacls C:\$Windows.~WS\*.* /T /grant administrators:F
> rmdir /S /Q C:\$Windows.~WS\
> ```

**Answer 2:**

> > Here's a batch file so you dont have to manually type it the next time. Remember to right click and run as Admin.
> >
> > [Windows10_Cleanup.bat < This will take you to Google Drive where you can download the file.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_DiTZFt_h35X2c2aFJJbm5MQUU/view?usp=sharing)
> >
> > If you get a SmartScreen error, just make the batch file yourself.
> >
> > 1) Open Notepad and copy the following

```
@echo off
@echo "This will delete the folder C:\$Windows.~WS and C:\$Windows.~BT after an update to reclaim space. Windows 10 only."
@echo --------------------------------
@echo If you get message "The system cannot find the file specified" it means the folder is already deleted.
@echo --------------------------------
PAUSE
RD /S /Q "C:\$Windows.~WS"
RD /S /Q "C:\$Windows.~BT"
@echo --------------------------------
@echo All done
@echo --------------------------------
PAUSE NULL
```

> > 2) Save as, select All file types and save as name.bat
> >
> > All done.

**Note:** 
I am still wondering if I should back up the files and use it to create media for x86 now, or save both for future.

Answer (score 1):

It's a staging directory for the update process.

There are some forum reports of safely deleting it, but [the only official word so far](https://twitter.com/CJCA915/status/626862066876420096) seems to be "not yet".

Comment: I deleted it.  It's safe.  It was used by the installer.  once installed it's not used

Comment: It might help to include what this file is as part of your answer.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek - Updated answer with details added below.