# Can I move $Windows.~BT to another volume?

Tags: windows-7, ssd, windows-update

I'm running windows 7 (x64) on a 90GB SSD for `C:\` drive. Consequently I'm constantly running out of space. I've already moved user documents, pictures etc. to another volume using junction links, but it's not enough.

Tonight I discovered there is ~4.2GB being consumed by [`$Windows.~BT`](https://superuser.com/questions/886098/what-is-the-windows-bt-folder), which I understand has been pre-loaded with Windows 10 upgrade files. I haven't might up my mind yet when or if I'll upgrade to Win10, but it certainly isn't now.

How can I move this folder and it's contents to another volume, while still leaving it's function intact?

It seems to be used for more than just Win10 upgrade. I also don't want to remove the files and have the next round of windows update just download them all over again, aside from being just wasteful we have a monthly bandwidth quota I'm always bumping into.

Comment: try this tool to move it: https://bitsum.com/junctionmaster.php

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer:

[$Windows.~WS folder in C:\ drive after Windows 10 Installation, Upgrade or Media Creation?](https://superuser.com/questions/947406/windows-ws-folder-in-c-drive-after-windows-10-installation-upgrade-or-media/961470#961470)

[What is the $WINDOWS.~BT folder?](https://superuser.com/questions/886098/what-is-the-windows-bt-folder?lq=1)

You can use the ESDs in the folders to create ISOs as well using an ESD to ISO tool or script for future upgrades or fresh Windows installs.

So save it externally if you'd like to :)

Comment: Hmmm. If I move the ESD's in the ~BT folder somewhere else won't the upgrade app just download them again, because they're missing? The ~WS thread doesn't seem to apply, it's about creating a copy of the upgrade files after they've been used.

Comment: The link is related but you have to better understand how these folders & MS upgrades work. 
No. I downloaded the upgrade, but I did not use it. I just saved the ISOs it created as well as the ESDs. 
It cannot download and install unless you explicitly allow it, but now it seems unless you block/ disable it this is what MS will do http://www.forbes.com/sites/gordonkelly/2015/10/30/windows-10-upgrades-now-automatic/ 

My suggestion is this: 
1. Find ways to disable automatic upgrade 2. Copy those folders elsewhere for future use -

Comment: WTF?! The Forbes article is downright maddening. I will move when I'm damn well ready Microsoft, my choosing, not yours. Alex thanks for your encouragement to persist. I shall do just that.

Comment: @mattwilkie - My aunts Win 8.1 machine went to Win 10.. with her support but pushed and prompted by MS through Windows Updates. I've disabled Windows Updates since I installed 8.1. Just downloaded Win 10 downloader for the ISOs in case/ when I move to Win 10 next year.. MAYBE!